# How to use an image defined as an XAML resource as an image control?

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, resources

Let's say we have the image defined as below.

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="SomeKey" Source="Path\To\The\Image.png" />
</Grid.Resources>
```

I want to use it as an image control somewhere. I try:

```
<Image Source="{StaticeResource SomeKey}" />
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use it as

```
<ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource SomeKey}" />
```

Hope that helps!

ps. Note that we must use `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource` so that if the image is used many times, a new/separate cloned image is created for each of those cases.